# Customization of items in listview based on templates

Tags: asp.net, xslt, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I have to display product and its description in listview/gridview,like any other eComm application.User want's to set the layout and attribute of product which he want to show while displaying the product.

I am planing to use templates, and provide user to generate templates(XSLT) based on the templates,the layout and attribute would be displayed,however I have no idea weather it is possible or not.Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how www.ventrian.com does their modules - especially the NewsArticles system.

Instead of providing the users an XSLT file to edit to control the layout they have their own templating / token system. There are a lot of modules that use this strategy, XSLT is a little serious if you are expecting 'users' to manage them. Even a lot of people who use DNN to build websites for others professionally have trouble wrapping their head around XML transformations.

But the answer to your question is definitely yes - you can provide XSLT files that transform your XML since it all works just like ASP .NET. But, most the popular modules provide a way for the user to customize layout that is not as complex as this.